# SD card issue in embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded, mmc

My setup: Embedded linux version 3.x on an ARM board with a SD card.

After running for a couple of months, I am getting this print in the console.

I want to understand this issue, and fix it.

Following are the lines thrown by the kernel in console:

```
mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt. mmcblk0: error -110
transferring data, sector 1050656, nr 1, cmd response 0x0, card status
0x0 end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1050656 FAT-fs
(mmcblk0p2): FAT read failed (blocknr 32)
```

Comment: Sounds like the SD card is dying; is the sector the same number each time? Or within a few hundred? Is it mounted with SD-card-appropriate flags, _e.g._ `noatime`? Here's [some other suggestions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/169/12028).

Comment: @BBM The card is damaged, this is not an Unix issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sdcard into another computer, and try to save the content with dd into a file, ignoring reading errors. Rewrite the image into a new sdcard and see if it works. command to save: # dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/.file.img conv=noerror,sync